# How to clone just master/main and on-demand/lazily pull branches only when they are checked out?

Tags: git

I'm working with a git repo that is in excess of 10gb with contributions being made constantly - it's creating a workflow issue for me.

Cloning the repo with `git clone git@...` takes about an hour and after checkout, if I haven't run `git pull` for longer than a day I get lots of `error: cannot lock ref` errors.

I believe Git by default will clone all remote branches locally, this isn't necessary for my workflow.

I would like to clone only `master` and only when I want to use a new branch, git will pull that branch from the remote on demand/lazily when I `git checkout branchname`

I have tried:

```
git clone --no-single-branch --depth 1 git@...
```

But I don't fully understand this command and it doesn't seem to work how I'd hoped

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811434/clone-only-one-branch, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/how-do-i-clone-a-specific-git-branch, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git?